# How to store and retrieve recyclerview data with sharedpreference

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-arrayadapter

I need to store data retrieved by recyclerview and show them for offline use.

Below is my code:

**RecyclerViewFragment**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    this.mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    initializeView();
    getPosts();
    return mView;
}

private void initializeView() {
    postsList = (RecyclerView) mView.findViewById(R.id.postsList);
    pBar = (LinearLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.pBar2);
    mFabButton = (FloatingActionButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.fabButton);
    mFabButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mFabButton.setRippleColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.accentColor));
    //layout manager
    notice = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.notice);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    postsList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mPostsItems = new ArrayList<PostsItem>();
    mHomeListAdapter = new HomeListAdapter(getActivity(), mPostsItems);
    postsList.setAdapter(mHomeListAdapter);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.swipeHome);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            M.L("called");
            // Refresh items
            setCurrentPage(1);
            getPosts();
        }
    });
    //setting up our OnScrollListener
    postsList.addOnScrollListener(new HidingScrollListener(layoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onHide() {
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mFabButton.getLayoutParams();
            int fabBottomMargin = lp.bottomMargin;
            mFabButton.animate()
                    .translationY(mFabButton.getHeight() + fabBottomMargin)
                    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2))
                    .start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onShow() {
            mFabButton.animate()
                    .translationY(0)
                    .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2))
                    .start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int currentPage) {
        }
    });

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onResume();
}

public void getPosts() {
    PostsAPI mPostsAPI = APIService.createService(PostsAPI.class, M.getToken(getActivity()));

    pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mFabButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    postsList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mPostsAPI.getPosts(getCurrentPage(), new Callback<List<PostsItem>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<PostsItem> postsItems, retrofit.client.Response response) {
            updateView(postsItems);

            notice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mFabButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            postsList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            M.T(getActivity(), getString(R.string.ServerError));
            pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            notice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}

private void updateView(List<PostsItem> postsItems) {

    if (getCurrentPage() != 1) {
        List<PostsItem> oldItems = mHomeListAdapter.getPosts();
        oldItems.addAll(postsItems);
        mHomeListAdapter.setPosts(oldItems);
    } else {
        mHomeListAdapter.setPosts(postsItems);
    }
    if (mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.fabButton) {
        mIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), SendPhotoActivity.class);
        startActivity(mIntent);
    }
}
public int getCurrentPage() {
    return currentPage;
}

public void setCurrentPage(int currentPage) {
    this.currentPage = currentPage;
}
}
```

**RecyclerItemClass**

```
public class PostsItem {
private int id;
public String status;
public String image;
private String date;
private String place;
private String youtube;
//private String link;
private int views;
private int ownerID;
private int privacy;
private int likes;
private int comments,totalComments;
private String ownerName;
private String ownerUsername;
private String ownerPicture;
private boolean liked;
private LinkModel link;

public PostsItem() {

}

public int getTotalComments() {
    return totalComments;
}

public void setTotalComments(int totalComments) {
    this.totalComments = totalComments;
}

public String getPlace() {
    return place;
}

public void setPlace(String place) {
    this.place = place;
}

public String getYoutube() {
    return youtube;
}

public void setYoutube(String youtube) {
    this.youtube = youtube;
}

public LinkModel getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(LinkModel link) {
    this.link = link;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getOwnerUsername() {
    return ownerUsername;
}

public void setOwnerUsername(String ownerUsername) {
    this.ownerUsername = ownerUsername;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getViews() {
    return views;
}

public void setViews(int views) {
    this.views = views;
}

public int getLikes() {
    return likes;
}

public void setLikes(int uses) {
    this.likes = uses;
}

public int getComments() {
    return comments;
}

public void setComments(int uses) {
    this.comments = uses;
}


public String getOwnerName() {
    return ownerName;
}

public void setOwnerName(String ownerName) {
    this.ownerName = ownerName;
}

public int getPrivacy() {
    return privacy;
}

public void setPrivacy(int privacy) {
    this.privacy = privacy;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getOwnerPicture() {
    return ownerPicture;
}

public void setOwnerPicture(String ownerPicture) {
    this.ownerPicture = ownerPicture;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public int getOwnerID() {
    return ownerID;
}

public void setOwnerID(int ownerID) {
    this.ownerID = ownerID;
}

public boolean isLiked() {
    return liked;
}

public void setLiked(boolean liked) {
    this.liked = liked;
}


}
```

Comment: no jux trying to show how am finding it had implementing sharedpreference in my app

Comment: serialize your Posts `response` to a `Base64 String`, then save that to `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: I've editted your question because we don't care about those extra comments. If you read it now, you can clearly see there is no question or problem that you've described. So, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Also, SharedPreferences are not designed for storing complex objects. I highly suggest you use SQLite as your datastore

Answer (score 0):

```
/* I not worked with retrofit library,In your background process when you are parsing the json just use */

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("id", id);
editor.putString("status", status); 
editor.apply();

/* For getting the shared Pref */
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
String id = sharedPreferences.getString("id", "default value");
String status = sharedPreferences.getString("status", "default value");
```

Comment: i want to store and retrieve an arraylist

Comment: it's bad practice to store  too much data into the shared pref,simply make a sqlite table and then dump all the data into the table.

Comment: how do i implement that

Answer (score 0):

```
/* add this line of code to ur fragment or activity here you get the arraylist. */ 

private MyOrderDatabase myOrder_db;
myOrder_db = MyOrderDatabase.getInstance(getActivity());
myOrderArrayLists = (ArrayList<OrderPogo>) myOrder_db.getAllOrder();
```

/* Make a sqlite table and add method like this which return a List */

```
public void addOrder(HashMap<String, String> orderHashMap) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID, orderHashMap.get(KEY_ID));
    values.put(KEY_LOADINGLOCATION,       orderHashMap.get(KEY_LOADINGLOCATION));
    values.put(KEY_LOCATION_DISTANCE, orderHashMap.get(KEY_LOCATION_DISTANCE));
    values.put(KEY_UNLOADINGLOCATION, orderHashMap.get(KEY_UNLOADINGLOCATION));
    values.put(KEY_QUANTITY, orderHashMap.get(KEY_QUANTITY));
    values.put(KEY_MATERIALNAME, orderHashMap.get(KEY_MATERIALNAME));
    values.put(KEY_SCHEDULE_DATE, orderHashMap.get(KEY_SCHEDULE_DATE));
    values.put(KEY_STATUS_NAME, orderHashMap.get(KEY_STATUS_NAME));
    values.put(KEY_TRUCK_TYPE, orderHashMap.get(KEY_TRUCK_TYPE));
```

//        values.put(KEY_NMBR_OF_TRUCK, orderHashMap.get(KEY_NMBR_OF_TRUCK));
//        values.put(KEY_COST_PER_TRUCK, orderHashMap.get(KEY_COST_PER_TRUCK));
//        values.put(KEY_QUOTE_TOTAL_AMOUNT, orderHashMap.get(KEY_QUOTE_TOTAL_AMOUNT));
//        values.put(KEY_QUOTES_TRUCK_TYPE, orderHashMap.get(KEY_QUOTES_TRUCK_TYPE));

```
    values.put(KEY_TRANSIT_PERIOD, orderHashMap.get(KEY_TRANSIT_PERIOD));
    values.put(KEY_QUOTE_AMOUNT, orderHashMap.get(KEY_QUOTE_AMOUNT));




    db.insert(TABLE_MYORDER_CONTENT, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public List<OrderPogo> getAllOrder() {
ArrayList<OrderPogo> orderList = new ArrayList<OrderPogo>();
String selectQuery = "";
selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_MYORDER_CONTENT;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
do {
OrderPogo orderPogo = new OrderPogo();
                  orderPogo.setLoadingLocation(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOADINGLOCATION)));
                    orderPogo.setUnloadingLocation(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_UNLOADINGLOCATION)));
                    orderPogo.setDistance(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOCATION_DISTANCE)));
                    orderPogo.setTonnes(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUANTITY)));
                    orderPogo.setMaterial(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_MATERIALNAME)));
                    orderPogo.setDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_SCHEDULE_DATE)));
                    orderPogo.setFlag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_STATUS_NAME)));
                    orderPogo.setTransitPeriod(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TRANSIT_PERIOD)));
                    orderPogo.setWaiting(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUOTE_AMOUNT)));
                    orderPogo.setTruckType(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TRUCK_TYPE)));

orderList.add(orderPogo);
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
cursor.close();
db.close();

return orderList;
}
```

Comment: please how do i implement this